# restart Ajax Request based on the jquery xhr object after Event: navigator.onLine

Tags: jquery, ajax, navigator

We are binding global ajax handlers to check if the browser went offline :

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings, response){  
   if(!navigator.onLine){  
        xhr.abort();  
   }  
}
```

then we are showing a dialog to the user that the browser went offline and bind for the 'online' event to hide the dialog when the browser turns online again.

Is there Anyway (even a hacky one) to restart the Ajax request based on the old which fits in the old context?

Comment: Independent of the actual task you are trying to achieve, navigator.onLine is not a reliable means of detecting a connection to the Internet or any network for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the cleanest approach I can think of:

1. A queue for caching AJAX request settings so each subsequent call doesn't overwrite the previous one
2. A conditional in the `ajaxSend()` handler that either pushes the calls on the queue for later or executes the entire queue.

   ```
   !(function($, window, undefined){
       var ajaxRequestQueue  = [],    // queue for requests that were made while offline
           isProcessingQueue = false;

       function processRequestQueue() {
           if (isProcessingQueue === true)
           {
               return;
           }

           isProcessingQueue = true;
           while (settings = ajaxRequestQueue.shift())
           {
               $.ajax(settings);
           }
           isProcessingQueue = false;
       }

       $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings, response){
           if (!navigator.onLine) {
               // abort the original request
               xhr.abort();
               // push a copy of the request's settings on the queue
               ajaxRequestQueue.push($.extend(true, {}, settings));
           }
           else if (ajaxRequestQueue.length > 0
                && isProcessingQueue        === false)
           // there are calls on queue and we haven't triggered 'ajaxSend' ourselves
           {
               processRequestQueue();
           }
       });

       // Bind to start processing the queue when the browser comes back online
       window.addEventListener("online", processRequestQueue);
   })(jQuery, window)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Well you might clone the object using jQuery and then restart your call when the browser goes back online

```
// Deep copy
var savedXhr= jQuery.extend(true, {}, xhr);
```

don't know if this really works, you could try it

EDIT - Ok i tried it and no way, you can't call send() on that object. This is because `xhr` is not the original request but a 'fake' object created by jQuery
A different approach might be this one: You save the settings object and then you start another $.ajax call with 
those settings.
Basically you do

var settingsSaved;

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings, response) {
    if (!navigator.onLine) {
        settingsSaved = jQuery.extend(true, {}, settings);
        xhr.abort();
    } else {
        //Send the request with the old settings
        $.ajax(settingsSaved);
        //abort the new request
        xhr.abort();
    }
}
```

Be really careful that this requre an accurate flow control because every time you call $.ajax you trigger another `ajaxSend` event...maybe you could simply start off a new `XMLHTTPRequest` using the values from the `settingsSaved` object.

Look at this fiddle, the first time you click a button, the call is aborted. The second time the call starts with the old settings and from then on all requests are normal

http://jsfiddle.net/hFmWX/

Comment: and how to restart the request based on the copied xhrObj?

Comment: @SepOSep i updated my answer, give it a look and see if it helps you